# How can I use ng-model to use the value of input field in Angular TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a simple calculator to get the values of input fields and use it on the same page but ng-model doesn't output value of input field.

I tried the same code on JsFiddle and it works fine but I am not sure why it doesn't work on the application.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-default" ng-app="">
<form class="form-group panel-body">
  <input ng-model="totalitems"  type="number">
</form>
<br>
<h2 class="label-default">{{totalitems}}</h2>
</div>
```

```
import { Component, Input, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Product Cost Calculator';

}
```

My application name is "calc" and I use `ng-app="calc"` on the body tag.

Comment: you html is based on angularjs1 and js code based on angular 2. both are not compatible. please choose one of them

Comment: @sachilaranawaka are you pointing to `[(ngModel)]`?

Comment: yep. and remove the angular 1 script, `ng-app`  also

Comment: I tried removing script line and ng-app but doesn't work.

Comment: please refer https://angular.io/guide/forms to get an idea about how the forms work in angular 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Angular 2 and in the view > form > input I used `ng-model` which is not compatible with Angular 2 and replaced with `[(ngModel)]`. I further revised the HTML code to get rid of the errors caused by using `[(ngModel)]` as I was using this in the form and input was missing `name` attribute. `[(ngModel)]` works when `name` attribute exists for input or place input without a form.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-app="">
<form class="form-group panel-body">
  <input [(ngModel)]="totalitems"  type="number" name="total_items">
</form>
<br>
<h2 class="label-default">{{totalitems}}</h2>
</div>
```